# SQL Query: JSON column diff

Tags: mysql, sql

I need yours ideas to solve the odd problem.

Table Structure : `id (increment), meta (JSON).`

Meta looks like:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "file_id": 957353,
      "user_id": 11111,
      "lastname": "x",
      "born_date": "1915-10-29",
      "file_path": "xxxx/xx/xx/xxxxxxxxx",
      "valid_date": "2099-01-01",
      "document_id": 33333,
      "document_type": "xxx_x_x_x",
    }
  ],
  "evaluation": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "file_id": 957353,
      "user_id": 11111,
      "lastname": "b",
      "born_date": "1915-10-29",
      "file_path": "xxxx/xx/xx/xxxxxxxxx",
      "valid_date": "2099-01-01",
      "document_id": 33333,
      "document_type": "xxx_x_x_x",
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to compare response with evaluation. I need something like diff or information that the data is identical or not. It must be a SQL query.

I'm looking for result like this:

```
id | identical | diff ?
 1 |    1      | null
 2 |    0      | 'xxxx => xxx'
 3 |    1      | null
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: if you want SQL solution then provide a fiddle with some sample data (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) and desired result for this data strictly. And specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to compare the two using the MySQL `JSON_CONTAINS` function (5.7 and up), but it will just return whether `response` contains the structure of `evaluation` or vice versa. This means you have to do the `JSON_CONTAINS` both ways to see if they are 100% equal or not.

With regards of the diff: this is not possible with the built in functions. It would be possible with a stored procedure that traverses both objects and determines if elements are present, differ or are missing and output it in a diff format.
There is one attempt on Stackoverflow that does something similar:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213951/mysql-json-diff-procedure